# Can i safely uninstall npm packages marked as NOTUSED by npm-check?

Tags: angular, npm, npm-package

I'm trying to refactor an Angular/Ionic project that I inherited. I ran [npm-check](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check) and got many NOTUSED dependencies as below, with a note to "*Check your code before removing as depcheck isn't able to foresee all ways dependencies can be used.*"

```
@babel/plugin-transform-block-scoping      NOTUSED?  Still using @babel/plugin-transform-block-scoping?
                                                      Depcheck did not find code similar to require('@babel/plugin-transform-block-scoping') or import from '@babel/plugin-transform-block-scoping'.
                                                      Check your code before removing as depcheck isn't able to foresee all ways dependencies can be used.
                                                      Use rc file options to remove unused check, but still monitor for outdated version:
                                                          .npmcheckrc {"depcheck": {"ignoreMatches": ["@babel/plugin-transform-block-scoping"]}}
                                                      Use --skip-unused to skip this check.
                                                      To remove this package: npm uninstall @babel/plugin-transform-block-scoping --save

@capacitor/android                         MAJOR UP  Major update available. https://capacitorjs.com
                                                      npm install @capacitor/android@4.7.3 --save to go from 3.9.0 to 4.7.3
                                           NOTUSED?  Still using @capacitor/android?
                                                      Depcheck did not find code similar to require('@capacitor/android') or import from '@capacitor/android'.
                                                      Check your code before removing as depcheck isn't able to foresee all ways dependencies can be used.
                                                      Use rc file options to remove unused check, but still monitor for outdated version:
                                                          .npmcheckrc {"depcheck": {"ignoreMatches": ["@capacitor/android"]}}
                                                      Use --skip-unused to skip this check.
                                                      To remove this package: npm uninstall @capacitor/android --save

cordova-plugin-fingerprint-aio             NOTUSED?  Still using cordova-plugin-fingerprint-aio?
                                                      Depcheck did not find code similar to require('cordova-plugin-fingerprint-aio') or import from 'cordova-plugin-fingerprint-aio'.
                                                      Check your code before removing as depcheck isn't able to foresee all ways dependencies can be used.
                                                      Use rc file options to remove unused check, but still monitor for outdated version:
                                                          .npmcheckrc {"depcheck": {"ignoreMatches": ["cordova-plugin-fingerprint-aio"]}}
                                                      Use --skip-unused to skip this check.
                                                      To remove this package: npm uninstall cordova-plugin-fingerprint-aio --save

webpack                                    NOTUSED?  Still using webpack?
                                                      Depcheck did not find code similar to require('webpack') or import from 'webpack'.
                                                      Check your code before removing as depcheck isn't able to foresee all ways dependencies can be used.
                                                      Use rc file options to remove unused check, but still monitor for outdated version:
                                                          .npmcheckrc {"depcheck": {"ignoreMatches": ["webpack"]}}
                                                      Use --skip-unused to skip this check.
                                                      To remove this package: npm uninstall webpack --save-dev
```

After checking the Angular code, if it doesn't reference a package by neither `require('package-name')` nor by `import from 'package-name'`, can I safely uninstall that package? How else can it still be used if it is not required or imported in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior of npm-check may vary based on how it performs its evaluations. If NOTUSED signifies that a package is not utilized by your code, it doesn't necessarily mean that other installed packages don't rely on it. Unfortunately, their documentation does not provide a clear definition of NOTUSED.

To proceed with caution, first create backups of your package.json and package-lock.json files. Then, you can attempt to remove or uninstall the packages one by one and rebuild your project. Remember to review your code before removing any packages, as depcheck might not be able to predict every possible usage of dependencies.

Comment: If a package is not being used (imported or required) by the code whatsoever, and it only exists in `package.json` dependencies list, do you think it can be deleted safely?

Comment: Not in all cases. 
As you stated: "Check your code before removing as depcheck isn't able to foresee all ways dependencies can be used". 
To be really safe, backup a copy your package.json and package-lock.json file somewhere, then try to remove them one after another and rebuild your project.

Comment: Thanks, if you update your answer with this I'll accept the answer.

Comment: I did update it now! :)